# Division by negative numbers

Tags: javascript, math, math.js

I am trying to calculate an angle in js using math js. I am experienced that when the division is between negative numbers js give me bad results. e.g. -6/-3 give me 20093 instead of 2.

How can I solve this? here below you can see a portion of console.log.
[image: Console.log]

Here is the code:

```
var num = math.eval(parseInt(p[1]) - parseInt(d3.event.y));
  var den = math.eval(parseInt(p[0]) - parseInt(d3.event.x));
  if (den==0){
    var angle = 0;
  }else{    
    var m = math.eval(num/den);
    if(m<1){
      theta = m*100;
    }else{
      theta = m*100;
    }
  }
```

Syntax in code is num/den as you can see.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about using the absolute value? `var m = Math.abs(num) / Math.abs(den);`

Comment: A side question: Accordng the internet math.eval() needs String as an argument. What will happen if you convert your argument to a String?

Comment: I'm not familiar with _math.js_, so what is `math.eval(num/den)` supposed to do? Why can't you just use `num / den` without `math.eval`? _edit:_ @reporter probably is right. Still I don't understand why you'd use a _math library_ for simple calculations like these.

Comment: `-6/-3 give me 20093 instead of 2` - no it doesn't, not in plain javascript and not even `math.eval(-6/-3)` nor even `math.eval("-6/-3")` - your question begins with a flawed argument

Comment: `here below you can see a portion of console.log` as your code has no console.log in it, I can only assume the code that produces those nonsense results is nothing like the code you've presented in the question

Comment: @LuudJacobs I used Math.js because if I use num/den gives me same bad results.

Comment: none of the code as shown requires `math.js` - you work with numbers, not strings of math expressions that need "evaluating" - console.log(-6/-3) logs 2 ... in every browser I've tried - which browser logs 20093?

Comment: Your results are `x * 100 + "93"` so there must be a line in your code that does that.

Comment: How about using actual angle computations, `theta = Math.atan2(num, den)`, then if necessary convert from radians to degrees.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do `-6/-3`.

Run this in your developer tools console: `alert(-6/-3);` and you will see.

I think `math.eval()` expects a string like `"-6/-3"`.

Comment: if you pass math.evil -6/-3 - you pass it 2 as an argument, which is possibly coerced into a string or perhaps recognised as a Number by mathjs - either way, what math.eval gets as an argument is `2` (with no way of knowing how it got that, so 6/3 should produce the same nonsensical result) ... the nonsense `20093` that the OP claims is probably a result of his **actual** code, not the stripped down code shown in the question :p

Comment: THX, great answer!

Comment: Tried to add an edit to correct 'math.evil' to 'math.eval' but edits must be 6 characters long... why is this?

Comment: @Martha I did it for you. Maybe it will be enough, when you add a comment.